# PyScripter auto-complete pop-up help?

Tags: arcpy, pyscripter

How do I get the pop-up help window that's part of the auto-complete to show more definitions of the tool being used?

For example in the attached image the definitions of "Buffer_analysis" inputs stop at "line_side".

I'd like to see the definitions for the other inputs as well (Lined_end_type, dissolve, etc...).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way to make Pyscripter show more in that hover-window. But you can get the full help in the interpreter by typing

```
print(arcpy.Buffer_management.__doc__)
```

This would work for any function that has a docstring.